# Navigating between components in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, forms, routes

I'm new to angular 4.

I have a project with 3 component: the root, component 1 and component 2.

When I clic on a button in the home page, i will be navigated to the google component page but the problem is that I see my home page buttons and pictures in the child component pages.

I did not get where is the problem, please any help, here is my components code.

- app.modules.ts

  ```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { PikachuComponent } from './pikachu/pikachu.component';
  import { GoogleComponent } from './google/google.component';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      PikachuComponent,
      GoogleComponent
    ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
  ```
- my app.component.html

  ```
  <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="fr">
  <head>
      <style>
     body 
    {
      background-image:   url("../assets/Background.jpg");
      background-size:    cover;
    }

    #languageSwitch
    {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .centerContent
    {
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* Bootstrap override */
    .btn-primary {
        color: #213239;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: white;
        border-radius: 50px;
        padding: 3px 30px 3px 30px;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        min-width: 150px;
        margin: 0px 80px;
    }

    .btn-checkin {
        color: #213239;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
        border-color: white;
        border-radius: 50px;
        padding: 3px 30px 3px 30px;
        white-space: nowrap !important;
        min-width: 150px;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .btn-group-lg > .btn, .btn-lg {
        padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
  <body>
      <body>
          <img src="./assets/Quadri_medium_2lignes_transparent.png" class="center">
      </body>
      <div style="text-align:center">
          <h3>{{curTime() }}</h3>
      </div>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" routerLink="/google"> <button class="btn-checkin" >Check In</button></a>
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" routerLink="/pikachu"> <button class="btn-primary">Check Out</button></a>
  </body>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </html>
  ```
- my google.component.html

  **Nom**



    

   Name is required

   
      **Prenom**

   

   
  Prenom is required


    **Email address**

    



  Email address is required

  ```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!Visiteur.form.valid">Next</button>
  ```
- my index.html

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="fr">
  <head>
      <style>
          body 
         {
           background-image:  url("../assets/GFIBackground.jpg");
           background-size:   cover;
         }

         #languageSwitch
         {
           text-align: right;
         }

         .centerContent
         {
           text-align: center;
         }

         /* Bootstrap override */
         .btn-primary {
             color: #213239;
             font-weight: bold;
             background-color: white;
             border-color: white;
             border-radius: 50px;
             padding: 3px 30px 3px 30px;
             white-space: nowrap !important;
             min-width: 150px;
           margin: 0px 80px;
         }

         .btn-group-lg > .btn, .btn-lg {
             padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
             min-width: 200px;
        }


     .center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 30%;
  }
       </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Visiteur GFI</title>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

I know it is not very clean but I need to get where is the error.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason this is happening:

When you have something on app level html file, it applies to all the pages within the complete application.

Probable solution:

Step 1: Restructure the code to have a Home component

If you want the pictures and buttons to appear only on home page and not when google component is loaded, you should clear your app.html file, remove all the background and buttons from it and restructure the code as below:

Create a home component.

--> In home.html.. Move your background and buttons code here.

```
    <img src="./assets/Quadri_medium_2lignes_transparent.png" class="center">

<div style="text-align:center">
    <h3>{{curTime() }}</h3>
</div>
```

--> Also move their related css to the home.css file.

Step2: Add Angular Routing to the app. May be this might help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_routing.htm

The default routing on app load should be to the home page, that way when you load the app, the home page is loaded with the background and buttons you wanted, and when google component is loaded, all the pictures and buttons from the home page are removed and the google component specific content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you would see the buttons because app component is your entry component, the router will ONLY replace

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

With the corresponding component, if you want the buttons to be exclusive to the home component then make a component named home and add this route 
`{path: ‘’, component: HomeComponent}`
With buttons in the home component